# Creating complex objects dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

Is it possible to create complex objects at runtime in javascript ? If so, what is the correct syntax ?

```
var food = {};
food["fruit"]["yellow"] = "banana";
food["meat"]["red"] = "steak";
food."fruit"."green" = "apple";
```

Comment: `var food = {};
food["fruit"] = {};
food["fruit"]["yellow"] = "banana";
food["meat"] = {};
food["meat"]["red"] = "steak";
food["fruit"]["green"] = "apple";`

Comment: My problem is this needs to happen dynamically, if I get food["meat"] 2 times I can't use food["meat"] = {} because the previous food->meat entry would be lost

Comment: Could you describe what you're trying to do in more detail? To me, this question is very unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to do. If you want to build that object up all at once, then you could do something like:

```
var food = {
    fruit: {
        yellow: 'banana',
        green: 'apple'
    },
    meat: {
        red: 'steak'
    }
};
```

If you need to piece it together one nested object at a time, then you just need to make sure that you are creating a new object to add properties to.

For example, your line:

```
food["fruit"]["yellow"] = "banana";
```

will probably fail because `food.fruit` does not exist.

You should do:

```
var food = {};
food.fruit = {};
food.fruit.yellow = 'banana';
```

Comment: I'm iterating through data in a file.I don't know if food is going to come along at all. So if there isn't any way around it I'll always use if(data.fruit == undefined) {var fruit = {}; } //Do something with data.fruit

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function to add data to your object.
e.g.

```
function addEntry(obj, entry) {
  if(entry.length < 2) return;
  if(entry.length === 2) obj[entry[0]] = entry[1];
  else {
    if(!obj[entry[0]] || typeof obj[entry[0]] !== "object") obj[entry[0]] = {};
    addEntry(obj[entry[0]], entry.slice(1));
  }
}

var data = [
  ["fruit", "yellow", "banana"],
  ["meat", "red", "steak"],
  ["fruit", "green", "apple"]
];

var obj = {};
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  addEntry(obj, data[i]);
}

console.log(obj);
```